# Using the case when then in sqlite and php

Tags: php, sqlite

Hi I'm battling to understand how to use the syntax of cases in sqlite.

What I'm trying to do

If Monday is in column 5 then show value in column 1 for the same row.

So for every row that has Monday in column 5 it will show the value of column 1.

Hope that makes sense

Thanks

EDIT

```
ID    SHOW NAME    AIRS   
1     The Test     Monday
2     Wrong        Tuesday
```

So it must look through AIRS and then it finds Monday and outputs the corresponding show name - The Test

Comment: Not sure I understand. Please post an example row and how you want it returned.

Comment: So you just want to `select show_name from your_table where airs = 'Monday'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to show all shows that air on Monday? No need for fancy `CASE`.

```
SELECT `SHOW NAME` FROM shows WHERE AIRS="Monday"

$sql = "SELECT `SHOW NAME` FROM shows WHERE AIRS='".$test."'"
```

Comment: Can I have a variable in place of Monday?

$test = 'Monday'; /line break/
SELECT `SHOW NAME` FROM shows WHERE AIRS="$test"

Comment: In php, you need to concatenate the string with the point operator, like I edited in my answer. If $test is userinput, escape the string with [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or use parameterized queries.